# Load dynamic properties after the reactjs bundle

Tags: reactjs, url, configuration, environment-variables

Below is my code. Here I want to read baseURL dynamically after react bundle the code. Means, I want to keep my production URL or developement URL outside the react js structure. 
Example: I create `.env` or property file outside of my package, from there I need to get this URL dynamically after the bundle.

```
import live from './../myservice/develop'
export default {    
    baseURL: "http:localhost:8080/myapp",
        .../live
};
```

Thanks in advance,
Arun

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, .env file is for when the app bundles. 
You could try:

```
baseURL: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? prodURL : localURL
```

do you really need the fully qualified URL? Can you use a relative URL?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I do not need to use fully qualified path. But I  didn't find the way to use relative path. Can you please suggest how to use relative path.

Comment: Can you provide more information about what the URL is for?